# Font awesome icon not showing while using CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

[My site](http://rentalslocator.ca/ca/on/london) doesn't seem to show the fonts from font awesome, even though I have included the css from cdn as shown here

```
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There should be a icon beside "tenant info" and "landlord info" and few others but those are some that are not showing up.

[image: image to show where icons are not showing]

The site looks fine running locally but does not on live.

**UPDATE**

Fixed, font folder was in the wrong spot

Comment: Where should the icons be located exactly? The css is loaded correctly

Comment: added the image to the original post

Comment: In the console there is an error, that `http://rentalslocator.ca/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf ` cannot be loaded, may be that's the problem

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin that was it thank you, i had accidently moved the font folder, weird that it worked locally, n e ways, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found @ https://fontawesomecdn.com

https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css

Use this Code in html-head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" 
 integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
```